# Is there a setting that controls icon color for the question/answer toolbar

Tags: support, design, editor

I don't know if this is a browser issue, underlying edit widget issue or a change made by Stack that has removed all color (or borders/separators) from the editor toolbar for the question/answer window. What I see now is:

[image]

The problem is that black & white alone makes it difficult for me to distinguish the icons (especially the heading, horiz-rule, and lists). Honestly, I can't remember exactly what they looked like previously, but I recall them being colored or having borders that made it much easier to distinguish what they were.

Has there been a change? If so, is there any way to select whether they appear with color or border?